# Are the phrases "some" and "many" determiners?

Tags: linguistics

Are they quantifiers or determiners, I am unsure about the answer to this question.

Comment: Both. Quantifier is a subtype of determinative. Their word class (part of speech) is determin**ative** and their function is determ**iner** Note the slight difference in spelling.

Comment: This will shortly be closed as an abuse of site rules, but if you're complaining about the above question 'Are the phrases [strings / words] “some” and “many” determiners?' this is akin to the 4th Earl of Sandwich complaining about having his name taken in vain. The question is so public-domain that it should and I hope will be closed here on ELU as either general reference or a multi-duplicate. _And note that Huddleston and Pullum dismiss the word-class label 'determiner'_.

Comment: (The above comment addressing a now-deleted answer, "Your IP adress and edited post has been sent to our English Linguistics Department Head. Please do not share the exam questions on social media next time.")